# HTML5 Canvas: Dragging outside of canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I am having issues implementing dragging functionality with HTML5 Canvas. I understand the lack of a scene graph etc., and have set up a way to identify drag a rectangle on mouse events.

However: the problem is losing mouse events when the mouse leaves the Canvas. If I drag outside of the canvas and release the mouse button, my code doesn't get a mouseup event to alter the dragging logic accordingly. The dragged object then remains stuck to my mouse until I start dragging again.

fabric.js [doesn't have this problem](http://fabricjs.com/per-pixel-drag-drop/), but I can't identify the relevant code in the library. How does it do this?

Answer (score 5):

First use boolean variable isMouseDragged which is set true after mouseDown and false after mouseUp (or another event I'll explain later)

You can handle dragging several ways.

```
if (mouse['isMouseDragged']) {
   mouse['xUp'] = e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
   mouse['yUp'] = e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
   ...
```

1. On mouse up calculate intersection between point where you pressed and released button (imagine it as line) and edge of canvas beyond which is mouse pointer (imagine it as another line). Put mouseUp position as intersection of these two lines.

   ```
   // FIRST OPTION
   if (mouse['mode'] == mouse['INTERSECTION']) {
       if (!mouse['isMouseOver']) {
           var edgeIntersect = mouseDraggedOut(mouse['xDown'], mouse['yDown'], mouse['xUp'], mouse['yUp']);
           mouse['xUp'] = edgeIntersect['x'];
           mouse['yUp'] = edgeIntersect['y'];
       }
   }
   ```
2. Hold your virtual mouse pointer (coordinates) inside a canvas.

   ```
   // SECOND OPTION
   if (!mouse['isMouseOver']) {
       if (mouse['mode'] == mouse['LOCK_INSIDE']) {
           var edgeIntersect = mouseDraggedOut(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, mouse['x'], mouse['y']);
           mouse['x'] = edgeIntersect['x'];
           mouse['y'] = edgeIntersect['y'];
       }
   }
   ```
3. Make coordinates onMouseUp = onMouseOut as you go out of canvas and set isMouseDragged false.

   ```
   // THIRD OPTION
   if (mouse['isMouseDragged']) {
      if (mouse['mode'] == mouse['MOUSEOUT_POS']) {
         mouse['xUp'] = mouse['xOut'];
         mouse['yUp'] = mouse['yOut'];
         mouse['isMouseDragged'] = false;
      }
   }
   ```

To calculate an intersect on edge of the canvas:

```
function mouseDraggedOut(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
// x1,y1 = mouseDown;  x2,y2 = mouseUp

var x3, y3, x4, y4;
var thisX, thisY;

if (x2 < 0) {// left edge
    x3 = 0;
    y3 = 0;
    x4 = 0;
    y4 = canvas.height;
    thisX = Math.round(x1 + (((x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3)) / ((y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1))) * (x2 - x1));
    thisY = Math.round(y1 + (((x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3)) / ((y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1))) * (y2 - y1));

    // I must do this for other checks, else corners (when two conditions are true) couldn't be handled
    // So I'll handle it one after another
    x2 = thisX;
    y2 = thisY;
}

if (x2 > canvas.width - 1) {// right edge
    x3 = canvas.width - 1;
    y3 = 0;
    x4 = canvas.width - 1;
    y4 = canvas.height - 1;
    thisX = Math.round(x1 + (((x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3)) / ((y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1))) * (x2 - x1));
    thisY = Math.round(y1 + (((x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3)) / ((y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1))) * (y2 - y1));
    x2 = thisX;
    y2 = thisY;
}

if (y2 < 0) {// top edge
    x3 = 0;
    y3 = 0;
    x4 = canvas.width - 1;
    y4 = 0;
    thisX = Math.round(x1 + (((x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3)) / ((y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1))) * (x2 - x1));
    thisY = Math.round(y1 + (((x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3)) / ((y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1))) * (y2 - y1));
    x2 = thisX;
    y2 = thisY;
}

if (y2 > canvas.height - 1) {// bottom edge
    x3 = 0;
    y3 = canvas.height - 1;
    x4 = canvas.width - 1;
    y4 = canvas.height - 1;
    thisX = Math.round(x1 + (((x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3)) / ((y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1))) * (x2 - x1));
    thisY = Math.round(y1 + (((x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3)) / ((y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1))) * (y2 - y1));
}

return {
    'x' : thisX,
    'y' : thisY
};
```

}

Look at the source code: http://jsfiddle.net/WolfeSVK/s2tNr/

Comment: Like the idea, the fiddle link is dead unfortunately.

Comment: I modified my answer (bad text formatting) and also jsfiddle link is now working...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to attach to the `mouseleave` event and not consider the button used for dragging to be down any more inside your logic.