# Word-wrap: break-down not working. Text overflow issue in draggable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draggable

Please help to solve this issue. Currently I have a div, that is draggable and the text inside is editable. And here the user can change the text size using input type range.

Is it possible to hide the letters of text-canvas, so that letters coming beyond the border of the image-canvas div and reach the `col-sm-8`?

Here when the user writes text without space, then that word go beyond the `col-sm-8`. How to solve this? I use `overflow:hidden` and `word-wrap:breakdown`, but it's not working.
[image]

```js
function submit_button() {
  /* ....Image upload function.. */
}
$(".text-canvas").draggable({
  containment: ".imageupload",
  create: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  drag: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  start: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  stop: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  }
});

$("#fontsize").on("change", function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $('.text-canvas').css('font-size', v + 'px');
});
```

```css
.text-canvas {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
.imageupload {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div name="anotherdiv">
    <input type="range" min="12" max="54" id="fontsize">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="parent-canvas">
    <div class="text-canvas" id="text-canvas" contenteditable="true">
      my text
    </div>
    <div class="image-canvas">
      <div class="imageupload" onclick="submit_button()">
        <img src="img.png">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I used `.text-canvas{ word-break: break-all; }`. Now the text is not going outside of the `col-sm-8` but it is still going outside of the image-div.

[image]

> **UPDATE** :currently I solved the issue by using `padding-right:10%`. But I
>   don't think is a good method. Please suggest a correct method.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321305/html5-canvas-dragging-outside-of-canvas

Comment: your snippet doesn't seem to reproduce the image you show above.  Could you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution:

You need to use the following properties in your `.parent-canvas` class:

```
.parent-canvas {
  display: inline-block; /* Display inline but retain the block-level characteristics */
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide the text if it overflows the container */
  position: relative; /* Text is removed from the normal flow with absolute position, use this to contain it */
}
```

After this you have two options, using [**`word-break`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) or **[`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)** in your `.text-canvas` class:

```
.text-canvas {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

**Code Snippet:**

```js
function submit_button() {
  /* ....Image upload function.. */
}
$(".text-canvas").draggable({
  containment: ".imageupload",
  create: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  drag: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  start: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  stop: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  }
});

$("#fontsize").on("change", function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $('.text-canvas').css('font-size', v + 'px');
});
```

```css
.text-canvas {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
.imageupload {
  z-index: -1;
}
.parent-canvas {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.text-canvas {
  word-break: break-all;
}
.image-canvas img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div name="anotherdiv">
    <input type="range" min="12" max="54" id="fontsize">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="parent-canvas">
    <div class="text-canvas" id="text-canvas" contenteditable="true">
      my text
    </div>
    <div class="image-canvas">
      <div class="imageupload" onclick="submit_button()">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or

```
.text-canvas {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

**Code Snippet:**

```js
function submit_button() {
  /* ....Image upload function.. */
}
$(".text-canvas").draggable({
  containment: ".imageupload",
  create: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  drag: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  start: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  stop: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  }
});

$("#fontsize").on("change", function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $('.text-canvas').css('font-size', v + 'px');
});
```

```css
.text-canvas {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
.imageupload {
  z-index: -1;
}
.parent-canvas {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.text-canvas {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.image-canvas img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div name="anotherdiv">
    <input type="range" min="12" max="54" id="fontsize">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="parent-canvas">
    <div class="text-canvas" id="text-canvas" contenteditable="true">
      my text
    </div>
    <div class="image-canvas">
      <div class="imageupload" onclick="submit_button()">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You can also use both if you like, they do not interfere with one another:

```
.text-canvas {
  word-break: break-all;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

---

### Code Snippet:

```js
function submit_button() {
  /* ....Image upload function.. */
}
$(".text-canvas").draggable({
  containment: ".imageupload",
  create: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  drag: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  start: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  stop: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  }
});

$("#fontsize").on("change", function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $('.text-canvas').css('font-size', v + 'px');
});
```

```css
.text-canvas {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
.imageupload {
  z-index: -1;
}
.parent-canvas {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.text-canvas {
  word-break: break-all;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.image-canvas img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div name="anotherdiv">
    <input type="range" min="12" max="54" id="fontsize">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="parent-canvas">
    <div class="text-canvas" id="text-canvas" contenteditable="true">
      ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
    </div>
    <div class="image-canvas">
      <div class="imageupload" onclick="submit_button()">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/sz7bc3z3/)

---

### TESTS:

*Windows 10 (64 bit):*

- Chrome 54.0.2840.71 m
- FireFox 49.0.2
- Edge 25.10586.0.0

*IOS 10.1:*

- Iphone 6 Safari Mobile

---

### Possible UX Improvement:

In my opinion, a little bit of user experience improvement, at least for Chrome and FF, could be adding the property `cursor: grab;` and `cursor: grabbing;` to let the user know it's a draggable element.

I didn't know it was a draggable item after I posted this answer. I guess I didn't pay real attention to whole question... people tend to interact with things fast.

You will need to decide if the `cursor: text;` is better than having the `grab` and `grabbing` ones.

Properties added to jQuery draggable classes:

```
.ui-draggable {
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}
.ui-draggable-dragging {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

**Code Snippet:**

```js
function submit_button() {
  /* ....Image upload function.. */
}
$(".text-canvas").draggable({
  containment: ".imageupload",
  create: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  drag: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  start: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  stop: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  }
});

$("#fontsize").on("change", function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $('.text-canvas').css('font-size', v + 'px');
});
```

```css
.text-canvas {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
.imageupload {
  z-index: -1;
}
.parent-canvas {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.text-canvas {
  word-break: break-all;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.image-canvas img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.ui-draggable {
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}
.ui-draggable-dragging {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div name="anotherdiv">
    <input type="range" min="12" max="54" id="fontsize">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="parent-canvas">
    <div class="text-canvas" id="text-canvas" contenteditable="true">
      my text
    </div>
    <div class="image-canvas">
      <div class="imageupload" onclick="submit_button()">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Notes:**

- To remove the unwanted space under the `img` element, use the property `vertical-align: middle;`.

---

### EDIT:

To prevent the text from overflowing vertically when `font-size` is increased, you need to set `height: auto;` to the `.text-canvas` class.

You can do this in different ways, one could be doing this:

```
$("#fontsize").on("change", function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $('.text-canvas').css({
    'font-size': v + 'px',
    'height': 'auto'
  });
});
```

This will set the `auto` value overriding the one set by jQuery UI.

> In the demo, the image is quite small and the font-size can get too
>   big, making its container dimensions exceed its parent's, make sure to
>   control that in production.

**Code Snippet:**

```js
function submit_button() {
  /* ....Image upload function.. */
}
$(".text-canvas").draggable({
  containment: ".imageupload",
  create: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  drag: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  start: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  stop: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  }
});

$("#fontsize").on("change", function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $('.text-canvas').css({
    'font-size': v + 'px',
    'height': 'auto'
  });
});
```

```css
.text-canvas {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
.imageupload {
  z-index: -1;
}
.parent-canvas {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.text-canvas {
  word-break: break-all;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.image-canvas img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.ui-draggable {
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}
.ui-draggable-dragging {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div name="anotherdiv">
    <input type="range" min="12" max="54" id="fontsize">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="parent-canvas">
    <div class="text-canvas" id="text-canvas" contenteditable="true">
      my text
    </div>
    <div class="image-canvas">
      <div class="imageupload" onclick="submit_button()">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Comment: +1 for your answer friend . Up voted . But the same situation i found in the js fiddle you given as example. Now the text that is not going out to the  right side border . But it is going out to the bottom border .

Comment: please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276905/processing-backwardundo-and-forwardredo-option-using-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Set the dimensions of `.parent-canvas` to be the same as the image, then use `overflow: hidden` and `position-relative` to contain the absolutely positioned text.

```
.parent-canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```js
function submit_button() {
  /* ....Image upload function.. */
}
$(".text-canvas").draggable({
  containment: ".imageupload",
  create: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  drag: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  start: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  stop: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  }
});

$("#fontsize").on("change", function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $('.text-canvas').css('font-size', v + 'px');
});
```

```css
.parent-canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.text-canvas {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
.imageupload {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div name="anotherdiv">
    <input type="range" min="12" max="54" id="fontsize">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="parent-canvas">
    <div class="text-canvas" id="text-canvas" contenteditable="true">
      my text
    </div>
    <div class="image-canvas">
      <div class="imageupload" onclick="submit_button()">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

```
word-break: break-all;
```

```js
function submit_button() {
  /* ....Image upload function.. */
}
$(".text-canvas").draggable({
  containment: ".imageupload",
  create: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  drag: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  start: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  stop: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  }
});

$("#fontsize").on("change", function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $('.text-canvas').css('font-size', v + 'px');
});
```

```css
.text-canvas {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  word-break: break-all;
}
.imageupload {
  z-index: -1;
}
.parent-canvas {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div name="anotherdiv">
    <input type="range" min="12" max="54" id="fontsize">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="parent-canvas">
    <div class="text-canvas" id="text-canvas" contenteditable="true">
      my text
    </div>
    <div class="image-canvas">
      <div class="imageupload" onclick="submit_button()">
        <img src="img.png">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi . Thank you friend . But i already applied  word-break: break-all;  . Please read my question .

Answer (score 0):

use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` or `text-overflow: clip;` it will hide the overflow text.

```js
function submit_button() {
  /* ....Image upload function.. */
}
$(".text-canvas").draggable({
  containment: ".imageupload",
  create: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  drag: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  start: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  stop: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  }
});

$("#fontsize").on("change", function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $('.text-canvas').css('font-size', v + 'px');
});
```

```css
.text-canvas {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
   text-overflow:  clip;/*ellipsis,initial*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
   width:3em;/*image div width*/
}
.imageupload {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div name="anotherdiv">
    <input type="range" min="12" max="54" id="fontsize">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="parent-canvas">
    <div class="text-canvas" id="text-canvas" contenteditable="true">
      my text
    </div>
    <div class="image-canvas">
      <div class="imageupload" onclick="submit_button()">
        <img src="img.png">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For parent**

```
.parent-canvas{
  display: inline-block;  
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

**For Child (text-canvas)**

```
.text-canvas {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

**Demo**

-Added background color for better demo purposes

-Immediate font size change

```js
function submit_button() {
  /* ....Image upload function.. */
}
$(".text-canvas").draggable({
  containment: ".imageupload",
  create: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  drag: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  start: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  },
  stop: function() {
    $("#text-canvas ").css("width ", 'auto');
  }
});

$("#fontsize").on("input change", function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $('.text-canvas').css('font-size', v + 'px');
});
```

```css
.text-canvas {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  word-break: break-all;
}
.imageupload {
  z-index: -1;
}
.col-sm-6 {
  background: red;  
}
.c {padding: 5px;}
.parent-canvas{
  background: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.text-canvas {
  background: yellow;
  min-width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-bootstrap/0.5pre/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="c col-sm-2">
  <div name="anotherdiv" style="display:flex">
    <div>8px</div>
    <input type="range" min="8" max="30" id="fontsize">
    <div>30px</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="c col-sm-12"></div>
<div class="c col-sm-6">
  <div class="parent-canvas">
    <div class="text-canvas" id="text-canvas" contenteditable="true">
      my text
    </div>
    <div class="image-canvas">      
      <div class="imageupload" onclick="submit_button()">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```